# Widgetkit conflicts JO Social Networks Tabs conflic and Page Peel Banner

Tags: jquery, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5.8 and Yootheme. I have Widgetkit and it worked pretty good until I installed Page Peel and JO Social Networks Tabs. I disabled one by one and it doesn't work, only Page Peel & JO Social are working together.

I don't know where to add this code:

```
// load jQuery, if not loaded before
if (!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')) {
  JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery', true);
  // add jQuery
  ...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code just incase you don't know already checks to see if jQuery is already being loaded on the site. If it isn't, it loads it.

So, you will need to replace the code currently being used to import jQuery and replace it with this.

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument(); //If this is already being used, remove it

if (!JFactory::getApplication()->get('jquery')) {
   JFactory::getApplication()->set('jquery', true);
   $document->addScript(JURI:root() . 'plugins/rest/of/path/jquery.js');
}
```

Comment: jQuery will be imported within the Page Peel plugin and the Social Network Tabs. Simply have a look in the files.